# Not able to compile oracle forms 12c on linux

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c

I am migrating my oracle forms from 6i to 12c. I am able to compile forms on windows environment but not on CentOS-6 Linux.

Following is error

```
FRM-30041: Position of item places it off of canvas.
Item: LOGIN_NAME
Block: LOGIN
Form: MAIN

FRM-30085: Unable to adjust form for output.
```

It seems the issue with object Library which system not able to find while compiling the form.

Following is my .bash_profile

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/usr/lib/jvm/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/12.2.1
export MW_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME
export WLS_HOME=$MW_HOME/wlserver
export WL_HOME=$WLS_HOME
export DOMAIN_BASE=$ORACLE_BASE/config/domains
export DOMAIN_HOME=$DOMAIN_BASE/frsdomain
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_161
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export FR_HOME=$ORACLE_HOME
export ORACLE_INSTANCE=$DOMAIN_HOME/config/fmwconfig/components/FORMS/instances/forms1
export FR_INST=$ORACLE_INSTANCE

# Forms compilation
export PATH=.:$FR_HOME/bin:$FR_HOME/forms/mesg:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$FR_HOME/oracle_common/jdk/jre/lib/amd64:$FR_HOME/lib:$FR_HOME/oracle_common/lib:$FR_HOME/oracle_common/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server
export FORMS_BUILDER_CLASSPATH=$FR_HOME/jlib/
export FORMS_PATH=/home/weblogic/app_home/forms
export REPORTS_PATH=/home/weblogic/app_home/reports
export TERM=vt220
export ORACLE_TERM=$TERM
```

Am i missing any variable? Can somebody help me with solution?

Comment: Could be some sort of cross-platform conversion issue.  Check the canvas size under its properties.  Make it huge (just to get around the compilation issue) and then see how it looks at runtime.  That might give you some clues as to what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with object Library we have to reattach object library into forms.